# How to get default application name in cli?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I want to create a framework that shows the application name on statup. Targeting command line interface applications.

Question: how can I get such an application name in a generic way?

Eg spring offers a property, but which is not set by default:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String appname;
```

And I don't want to set that property explicit. Looking for some kind of "default application name".

In a Java EE container there is also the following option:

```
String myApplicationName = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:app/AppName");
```

But how about `CLI` apps? How can I get some kind of generic application name?

Comment: What is the application name in a cli program? can you explain? It is the Name of the jar or the main class?

Comment: I'm just looking for some name to "identify" the application. Eg the jar name would be fine. Main class also.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but you can set defaults e.g.: `@Value("${spring.application.name:defaultName}")`. Moreover, you can pass these variables as command line inputs `$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.application.name=mycoolproject`

Comment: `<Mainclass>.class.getName()` where `<Mainclass>` is the Name of the main class

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get, if I interpreted correctly your question, is to:

1. find which class is running `public static void main(String [] args)` method
2. get its `simpleName`
3. store aforementioned name into a system property

and in order to do so, you have two options:

- call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, and inspect its tail element. But this has to be executed in the main thread as well, otherwise you wont retrieve the correct `StackTraceElement`;
- call [Thread:getAllStackTraces()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()), and parse the entire map to identify the main Thread, get the corresponding value, and pick its last `StackTraceElement`

Once you have `StackTraceElement`, you can call [StackTraceElement:getClassName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getClassName()) which will return something like

> scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner

Split the string, save it into a system property, and you're good to go.

Hope it will help you.